# Empty string is a file? ( if [ ! -f "" ] )

Tags: files, string, test

The script is called **isFile.sh** and looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo $1
echo $2

if [ ! -f $1 ]; then
  echo "$1 (arg1) is not a file"
fi

if [ ! -f $2 ]; then
  echo "$2 (arg2) is not a file"
fi
```

First I created a file by doing `touch file.exist`.

And I ran `bash isFile.sh file.exist file.notexist` 
The output was:

> file.exist
>
> file.notexist
>
> file.notexist (arg2) is not a file

---

Then I ran `bash isFile.sh "" file.notexist`
The output was:

> (# empty line)
>
> file.notexist
>
> file.notexist (arg2) is not a file

Expected output is:

> (# empty line)
>
> file.notexist
>
> (arg1) is not a file
>
> file.notexist (arg2) is not a file

Can somebody explain why?

Comment: Are you sure about `echo$1`? I would think it is `echo $1` (better cut an paste). And welcome!

Comment: @ Volker Siegel, Sure it's `echo $1`, I edited my question, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that `[ ! -f $1 ]` becomes `[ ! -f ]` after expansion (and not `[ ! -f "" ]` as you thought!), so instead if checking if a given file exists, `[` checks if the `-f` string is empty or not. It's not empty, but thanks to `!` the final exit code is `1`, thus the `echo` command is not executed.

That's why you need to quote your variables in POSIX shells.

Related questions:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/243481)
- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/243481)

Comment: Thanks for mention me add quotes on variables, but still I can't get the output right. Means I still get the same output after I double quoted my variable in the IF condition. Change $1 to " " or  ' ' doesn't work either.

Comment: @KitisinKyo, do you mean that `bash -c '[ -f "" ] && echo yes'` outputs `yes` for you? What system is that?

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas,  Nope, `bash -c '[ -f "" ] && echo yes'` had no output. I'm using CentOS 7

Comment: @KitisinKyo, yet you're saying in the comment above that `if [ ! -f "" ]; then echo ...; fi` outputs nothing. Try running the script with `bash -x` to see what happens.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas, I edited a wrong script, the code worked, I was dumb.

Comment: @KitisinKyo If this answer solved the problem please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Or add your own answer if the actual solution differs from this one. That way other users with similar problems may benefit from it.